# Draw a second identical polygon inside a primary one with a certain gap

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The code below sketches a polygon on an image. I would like to draw a second identical shape inside the primary one with a gap of 0.3m. I have tried a couple of solutions but none of them worked in all use cases.

Please refer to the attached screenshot.

[image]

Context: The shape is drawn by combining a group of selected points using the QPolygon class.

```
import sys
from sympy import Polygon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLine, Qt, QPoint, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter,QColor,QPolygon
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic





class MyApp(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height =1200,800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width,self.window_height)
        layout= QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.pix  = QPixmap('image.jpg')
        self.resize(self.pix.width(),self.pix.height())
        # self.pix.fill(Qt.white)
        # tableau
        self.point = QPoint()
        self.tab =[]

   

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor('red'))
        pen.setWidth(3)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(),self.pix)
      
        if not self.point.isNull():
            # rect = QRect(self.begin,self.destination)
            # painter.drawRect(rect.normalized())
            line = QPoint(self.point)
            painter.drawPoint(line)
            

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.point = event.pos()
            # self.destination = self.begin
            

            
            self.update()
        

    # def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
    #     if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
    #         self.point = event.pos()
    #         self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        painter = QPainter(self.pix)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # rect = QRect(self.begin,self.destination)
            line = QPoint(self.point)
            pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor('red'))
            pen.setWidth(3)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawPoint(line)
            painter.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
            
            self.tab.append(self.point)
            print(self.point.x,self.point.y)
            
            self.point = QPoint()
            # w = (rect.width()*12.5)/1056
            # h = (rect.height()*12.5/1056)
            # a=w*h
            # print(w, h,a)
            self.update()
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            points = QPolygon(self.tab)
            pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor('red'))
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawPolygon(points)
            #print(self.tab[0])
            polytab=[]
            for i in self.tab:
                polytab.append((i.x(),i.y()))   
            print(Polygon(*polytab).area*(12.5/1056)*(12.5/1056))
            print((self.tab[0].x()-self.tab[1].x())*(12.5/1056))
            self.tab=[]
            self.update()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''QWidget{font-size:30px}''')
    myAPP = MyApp()
    myAPP.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is given a vertex so the associated edges must be translated in a parallel way and the intersection of these lines is a point of the desired polygon.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QLineF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen, QPolygonF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


def calculate_inner_polygon(polygon, offset):
    if polygon.count() < 3:
        return QPolygonF()
    points = []
    for i in range(polygon.count()):
        pp = polygon[(i - 1 + polygon.count()) % polygon.count()]
        pc = polygon[i]
        pn = polygon[(i + 1 + polygon.count()) % polygon.count()]

        line_0 = QLineF(pp, pc)
        normal_0 = line_0.normalVector()
        normal_0.setLength(offset)
        line_0.translate(normal_0.dx(), normal_0.dy())

        line_1 = QLineF(pc, pn)
        normal_1 = line_1.normalVector()
        normal_1.setLength(offset)
        line_1.translate(normal_1.dx(), normal_1.dy())

        t, point = line_0.intersects(line_1)

        if t != QLineF.NoIntersection:
            points.append(point)
    return QPolygonF(points)


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(1200, 800)
        self._points = list()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor("white"))

        if not self._points:
            return

        pen_width = 3
        offset = -8

        pen = QPen(QColor("red"))

        outer_polygon = QPolygonF(self._points)
        inner_polygon = calculate_inner_polygon(outer_polygon, offset)

        for polygon in (outer_polygon, inner_polygon):
            pen.setWidth(pen_width)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawPolygon(polygon)
            pen.setWidth(2 * pen_width)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            for point in polygon:
                painter.drawPoint(point)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self._points.append(event.pos())
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyApp()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello eyllanesc, Thank you for your fast response. The problem I have with this is that I am using points to connect complex polygons, which makes it harder to guess whether to put -delta or +delta for certain shapes. Do you know of a logic that might work for this scenario

Comment: @Amen0 see my update

Comment: You sir are a legend. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Amen0 Review the [tour]